# tabindex navigation using "enter key" not working in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have used below code for tabindex navigation using "enter key" in html form.It works fine as per my requirement,but this code is  not working in dropdown.Please check below code and advise how to do this..

```
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    var form = event.target.form;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
    form.elements[index + 1].focus();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `if` statement to include the `select` node as example below.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' || event.target.nodeName === 'SELECT')) {
    var form = event.target.form;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="checkbox">
<select>
<option>123</option>
</select>
<input type="radio">
</form>
```